# Creating a User Profile page using OneToOne field with User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm currently using Django all-auth, and it has a /accounts/profile page which I want to create/populate with a form which updates user information.

I have a Teacher field, which extends the User Model using OneToOne field.

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teacher_logo = models.FileField()
```

This teacher model is what I want the user to update in /accounts/profile.

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('availability', 'bio','teacher_logo')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        teacher_form = TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.teacher)
        if user_form.is_valid() and teacher_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            teacher_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('users:index')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        teacher_form = TeacherForm(instance=request.user.teacher)
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'teacher_form': teacher_form
    })
```

**template users/profile.html**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ user_form.as_p }}
  {{ teacher_form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/$', views.update_profile, name='Update-Profile')
```

I can use an update view, but then I need to specify  in the URL, which seems an incorrect way of doing it; Also, users will be able to edit someone else profiles.

When I run the above, I get a complaint that 'User' object has no attribute 'teacher'.

When I remove `.teacher` from  `TeacherForm(instance=request.user.teacher)` It loads the page with the form, but when I update, it still gives me the same complaint (removed in both places in views.py)

**EDIT: models.py extra**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.Teacher.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set related name as `Teacher`, so you need:

```
teacher_form = TeacherForm(instance=request.user.Teacher)
#                                               ^^^^
```

or better set `related_name` to 'teacher'

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(
         User, 
         on_delete=models.PROTECT,
         related_name='teacher')
#                     ^^^
```

Comment: or just don't set it at all, in which case the default will be `teacher` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I still get: Exception Value: 
'User' object has no attribute 'teacher' Exception Location: /Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/DjangoWebsite/accounts/models.py in save_user_profile, line 45 (the file doesn't have line 45)

Comment: did you create the `Teacher` instance?

Comment: Fixed it, there was an additional part in the models.py (which I added to the edit, for future readers).