# updating UserProfile (OneToOne model to Django User model)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and creating a Django project with an account system. I extended the User model with a one-to-one UserProfile model.

However, I am having problems saving the data in the UserProfile model (saving to User model is having no problem). I tried to follow this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936087/creating-a-user-profile-page-using-onetoone-field-with-user-model?rq=1) to fix it but ran into *AttributeError at /account/login/
'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'* errors which is saying there are errors with `instance.UserProfile.save()` under models.py

How do I get the UserProfile form to save and fix this no attribute error?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import datetime
from django.conf import settings

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(
                User, 
                on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                blank=True, 
                null=True, 
                unique=True,
                related_name='userprofile'
        )
        bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True)
        campus = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
        website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
        phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
        birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
        gender = models.CharField(default='', blank=True, max_length=20)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.UserProfile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
    # Edit User form
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
        )
# Edit User Profile form
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'bio',
            'campus',
            'birthday',
            'gender',
            'website',
            'phone',
            'image',
        )
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.UserProfile.user)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            #user.username = user.email
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('/account/profile')
    else:
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
        user_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    args = {
        'user_form': user_form, # basic user form
        'profile_form': profile_form # user profile form
        }
    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

templates accounts/edit_profile.html

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile')
```

**SOLUTION:**

in **models.py** only have one receiver and change `else:
instance.UserProfile().save()` to `else:
instance.userprofile().save()`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofile.save()
```

in **views.py** fix typos

change `profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.UserProfile.user)` to `profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two handlers listening on the same signal (`post_save`) and your `save_user_profile` function runs before `create_user_profile` can find a chance to create the `UserProfile` instance.

I would suggest consolidating both handlers into one, such as:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.userprofile.save()
```

Comment: Ah, I copied your code verbatim assuming that it was correct. See my updated answer.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, I didn't even catch that last one--thanks!